# How do I coalesce Stackdriver logs/sinks into one BigQuery project/dataset?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

Setting up Stackdriver log sinks to BigQuery is straightforward.

However, I have lots of projects, and instead of each export sink going to its corresponding project, I'd like to coalesce the logs from all my projects to **one** dedicated project.

The configuration in the Stackdriver sink config doesn't appear to let me select a different project to send the logs to.

[image]

---

**How do I select a different project/dataset?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select the `'Custom destination'` option. This will allow you to plug in a different project/dataset. The default datasets you see are always tied to whichever project you've currently got selected, so you can't select a different project/dataset.

Instead:

1. Select `'Custom Destination`'
2. Add the destination using this format: `bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/datasets/[DATASET_ID]`
3. Give the sink writer editor permissions on the said project/dataset in step 2.

See more [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/).

Answer (score 1):

If all of your projects are under a Cloud Folder or under the same organization, you can also create an Aggregated Export as documented in https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_exports.

The aggregated sink lives in the folder or org, and exports all logs of children projects to the same destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Bigquery Audit sink at Org level using gcloud command as below

```
gcloud logging sinks create my-org-bq-sink bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/my-gcp-project/datasets/my_bq_audit_dataset --include-children --organization=MY_ORG_ID
```

Hope this helps.